# Query Builder : orderBy not working after group by

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I have a primary query which will run following way. And I had to check a condition and if the condition fulfilled it will add a statement with the existing query. But it doesn't work in right way means i couldn't get the orderby function run with the existing one? Why's that or how to solve this?

```
$query = DB::table('users')
               ->join('products','products.auth_id','users.id')
               ->Join('reviews','products.id','reviews.product_id')
               ->select('products.*','users.avatar',DB::raw('(sum(rating)/count(user_id)) as rating'))             
               ->where('products.status','=','1')           
               ->groupBy('products.id')   
               ->latest();


if($request->get('dropdown')!='0' && $request->get('dropdown')=='desc')
{
   $query->orderBy('products.regular_price', 'desc') ;
}

$products = $query->get();
```

Comment: Your query appears to have a problem.  Can you edit your question and show the raw MySQL query which you intend, along with the expected output?

Comment: I suspect starting this query from the products table, not the users table would help. But I see you are aso relying on a "quirk" of MySQL (which allows an abridged `group by` clause). In recent versions that weird default behaviour of `group by` has changed and it is more standards compliant now than it used to be so any query that has an abridged `group by` may fail  due to this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if($request->get('dropdown')!='0' && $request->get('dropdown')=='desc')
{
   $query = $query->orderBy('products.regular_price', 'desc') ;
}
```

Note : You have added `latest()` function in your query. This function added following in your query

`ORDER BY created_at DESC`

Default parameter of `latest()` is `created_at`

Comment: the problem was happening due to latest() when i removed that it works fine even in my Query but with latest() your solution doesn't work .. can you check it once again please?

Comment: Why you add latest in your query. I already explain in my answer How latest work. @User57

Comment: what if i need to show the latest product and based on price.. there are other lines of statement with the existing one i didn't post.. so I need to keep the latest one .

Comment: Debug your query. Call `toSql()` instead of `get()` and it will return raw sql